# Wald test with panel ols in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels, linearmodels

I am trying to test hypothesis that all intercepts coefficients in pooled OLS are equal to zero with: F-test, Likelihood Ratio and Wald-test. I have some problems with the last one.

Here is the code 
`PanelOLS((table1['Return']-table1['RF']), sm.add_constant(table1[['Mkt_RF','SMB','HML']])).fit().wald_test()`

in statsmodels you can put your hypothesis in wald_test method in string format, however it seems not to work in liner_model PanelOLS package. Am I doing it in a wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The problem is in syntax.

For example if I want to check if SMB=0 I do:

```
PanelOLS((table1['Return']-table1['RF']), sm.add_constant(table1[['Mkt_RF','SMB','HML']]), entity_effects=True).fit().wald_test(formula='SMB = 0')
```

which is a bit different from statsmodels